# JavaFX Tableview not populating data to column

Tags: javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I am trying to create a TableView with 1 counter + 4 value columns. But for some unknown reason, columns val3, val4 are not getting populated in the tableview. I have updated the getVal2() method with "val3.get()", and I could see the val3 value in column of Value2. So, I suspect that there is some problem with reading to column Value3. I have also checked the naming convention/camel-casing. It looks fine to me. Can any help me fix this ?

```
        ObservableList<Counters> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    Iterator<String> counterIterator = counterMap.keySet().iterator();
    while(counterIterator.hasNext()) {
        String counter = counterIterator.next();
        String[] values = counterMap.get(counter);
        String val1 = "a", val2 = "b", val3 = "c", val4 = "";
    Counters counters = new Counters(counter, val1, val2, val3, val4);
        data.add(counters);
    }

    TableView<Counters> table = new TableView<Counters>();
    table.setEditable(true);

    TableColumn<Counters, String> counter = new TableColumn<Counters, String>("Counter");
    counter.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Counters, String>("counter"));
    TableColumn<Counters, String> val1 = new TableColumn<Counters, String>("Value1");
    val1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Counters, String>("val1"));
    TableColumn<Counters, String> val2 = new TableColumn<Counters, String>("Value2");
    val2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Counters, String>("val2"));
    TableColumn<Counters, String> val3 = new TableColumn<Counters, String>("Value3");
    val3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Counters, String>("val3"));
    TableColumn<Counters, String> val4 = new TableColumn<Counters, String>("Value4");
    val3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Counters, String>("val4"));

    table.getColumns().add(counter);
    table.getColumns().add( val1);
    table.getColumns().add( val2);
    table.getColumns().add( val3);
    table.getColumns().add( val4);
    table.setItems(data);




public static class Counters {

    private SimpleStringProperty counter, val1, val2, val3, val4;

    public Counters(String counter, String val1, String val2, String val3, String val4) {
        this.counter = new SimpleStringProperty(counter);
        this.val1 = new SimpleStringProperty(val1);
        this.val2 = new SimpleStringProperty(val2);
        this.val3 = new SimpleStringProperty(val3);
        this.val4 = new SimpleStringProperty(val4);
    }

    public String getCounter() {
        return counter.get();
    }

    public void setCounter(String counter) {
        this.counter.set(counter);
    }

    public String getVal1() {
        return val1.get();
    }

    public void setVal1(String val1) {
        this.val1.set(val1);
    }

    public String getVal2() {
        return val2.get();
    }

    public void setVal2(String val2) {
        this.val2.set(val2);
    }

    public String getVal3() {
        return val3.get();
    }

    public void setVal3(String val3) {
        this.val3.set(val3);
    }

    public String getVal4() {
        return val4.get();
    }

    public void setVal4(String val4) {
        this.val4.set(val4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a copy-paste typo in

```
TableColumn<Counters, String> val4 = new TableColumn<Counters, String>("Value4");
val3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Counters, String>("val4"));
```

Should be

```
TableColumn<Counters, String> val4 = new TableColumn<Counters, String>("Value4");
val4.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Counters, String>("val4"));
```

and val4 is always `val4 = ""` thats why it looks like they both are empty

Comment: I guess I was blind enough not to see that :)